# Adding to existing map with Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream, maps

```
Map<Long, Employee.status> prevStatus = empRecords.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(employeeRecord::getEmloyeeID,
                                employeeRecord::getEmployeeStatus));
```

I already have the above code, I need to add a similar operation but instead of creating a new Map I want to add the result to the existing map.

```
prevStatus = empRecords.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.**toMap**(employeeRecord::getEmloyeeID,
                                    employeeRecord::**getUSEmployeeStatus**));
```

Comment: Perhaps you should just use `forEach` instead of collecting, and call `prevStatus.put`. Alternatively, you can wrap your second stream pipeline in `prevStatus.putAll()` (but you may have to make sure `prevStatus` is not immutable (perhaps by specifying what map class to use in step 1)

Comment: Instead of foreach & putting manually, we can use existing Collectors.toMap() itself with additional args. Check My answer. That could be what you exactly want.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new `Map` and add its entries to the existing `Map`:

```
prevStatus.putAll(
    empRecords.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(employeeRecord::getEmloyeeID,
                                        employeeRecord::getUSEmployeeStatus)));
```

Or you can use `forEach` instead of `collect`:

```
empRecords.stream()
          .forEach(emp -> prevStatus.put(emp.getEmloyeeID (),
                                         emp.getEmployeeStatus()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected code

```
empRecords.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(employeeRecord::getEmloyeeID,
                                            employeeRecord::getEmployeeStatus,(newVal,oldVal)->newVal,()->existingMap));
```

Where `(newVal,oldVal)->newVal` logic is for what if key is already present in existing Map and
`existingMap` is your existing map. Make sure existingMap is not null. If it is null going with new HashMap what you shared in your code itself fine.